# Error while generating nodes with neo4j via neo4j-console

Tags: database, rest, batch-file, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to put data in my graph DB using neo4j. I'm new in the field and I don't find it easy to use the [batch import tool](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) that Michael Hunger wrote. 
My goal is to generate at least 10000 nodes with just one property set. So I wrote a python script that generates 10000 lines of Cypher queries like "CREATE (:label{ number : '3796142470'})". 
I put them in the console and execute them but I get this exception:

**StackTrace**:

```
scala.collection.immutable.List.take(List.scala:84)
org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.ast.SingleQuery.checkOrder(Query.scala:33)
```

Am I doing something wrong? In case the only way to generate those nodes is to use a batch/rest API, could you suggest me a easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
CREATE (:label{ number : '3796142470'})
```

to look like:

```
CREATE (n1:Label { number : '3796142470'})
```

So you are following convention:

```
CREATE (n:Person { name : 'Andres', title : 'Developer' })
```

Put them into a file (say import.txt) and then:

```
bin/neo4j-shell -file import.txt
```

See http://blog.neo4j.org/2014/01/importing-data-to-neo4j-spreadsheet-way.html for more details.

Comment: I followed your suggestion Max but I solved the problem putting a semicolon after every CREATE statement.
I am trying to visualize the whole graph now via http://localhost:7474/browser/ but it seems like I can't if the nodes exceed the 1000